# Prove that, if the range of a convergent sequence has a limit point, the sequence must converge to that limit point.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Have to prove the following- if the range of a convergent sequence has a limit point, the sequence must converge to that limit point.

Not sure how I can proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Definitions-

> **Convergent**- Assume  $a_1,a_2,a_3, \cdots$ is an infinite sequence of real numbers, and  $L \in R$. We say that the sequence converges to  $L$ (and write  an→L) iff $∀\epsilon>0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$, $\forall n>N,|a_n−L|<\epsilon$.

> **Limit Point**- A limit point of a sequence $(a_n)$ in a topological space $X$ is a point $x$ such that every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contains all points of the sequence with numbers above some $n(U)$.

My thoughts were that a convergent sequence has only one limit point. Not sure where to go from here (or if this is even correct)

Comment: Write down the definitions of "convergent" and "limit point" and see how you might match one to the other. If you're still stuck, [edit] the question to show us just were.

Comment: @EthanBolker added the definitions.

Comment: Your last thought is correct. If you're not sure why, try to prove it. The two definitions you cite are at different levels of abstraction. One is for the reals and one for a general topological space, If you rewrite the first in the language of the second you mayu be able to proceed.

Comment: @CalvinLin I deleted my comment.  I misread the posting, and thought that the posting was asking whether a sequence that had a limit point had to be convergent.  I am having an off day.

Comment: @EthanBolker The last thought is *not* true in general, although it is true for real numbers in the usual (metric) topology. Consider the set $A = \{a, b\}$ and the topology $T = \{\emptyset, A, \{a\} \}$. Consider the sequence $x_n = a$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Note that $a$ and $b$, different, are both limit points.

Comment: @K.Jiang Fair point. It is true for "reasonable" topologies. That one is pathological. (It's been a while since graduate school so I won't venture a definition of  "reasonable".)

Comment: Your definition of limit point is surely incorrect. Check carefully. That’s the definition of the limit of the sequence, not of a limit point of a subset of a topological space.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be a limit point of the sequence $(x_n)$. By definition, for any neighborhood $U$ of $L$, there exists an integer $N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $x_n \in U$ for each $n > N$. This is precisely the same as saying that $(x_n)$ *converges* to $L$, by definition. There is nothing substantial to check.

This isn't your main question, but note that the limit point of a sequence need not be unique for a general topological space. If the space is Hausdorff (e.g., real numbers in the usual topology), then limit points do happen to be unique. For suppose $(x_n)$ converges to $L$, and take any $M \ne L$. If the space is Hausdorff, there exists neighborhoods $V$ of $L$ and $W$ of $M$ such that $V \cap W = \emptyset$. Since $(x_n)$ converges to $L$, there exists some $N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $x_n \in V \implies x_n \notin W$ for all $n > N$. Therefore, $(x_n)$ does not converge to $M$.

Comment: Your second sentence is incorrect. Be careful. Oh, OP gave a mistaken definition.

Comment: The provided definition is actually fine, since it is clear that they are referring to the limit point *of a sequence*, and not of a subset (which would be different). See second paragraph here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulation_point.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to frame it, given that it seemed to flow from the definition